# Is it possible to get a list of all image files from gallery (Android & iOS) using AIR

Tags: mobile, air, gallery, filelist

I'm working on a project for Android & iOS, using Adobe AIR.

The idea is to have one component which is basically a list populated with thumbnails of all images existing in Gallery app on mobile (Android  & iOS).

Is there some solution for this? Is there a way to get a listing of all image files inside a Gallery?

I would not like to use "cameraRoll.browseForImage();" cause I don't want any popups.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to iOS development using AIR, but it seems you might have to use a native extension to do your task. Some searching through up https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-ImagePicker as a possible contender.

Comment: Not good. ANE-ImagePicker will display a pop-up dialog (browser) for choosing images. I need something to do it seamlesly. Also, I didn't manage to get it working on Android, don't know why... :/

Answer (score 0):

for android, edit your xml file to something like this

```
     <android>
    <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/> 
                <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/> 
                <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/> 
                <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/> 
     <application>    
 <activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirImagePicker.AirImagePickerActivity"  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|fontScale" />
                         </application>
</manifest>]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
  </android>
```

and use this ane http://robotdev.co.uk/files/AirImagePicker.zip

Comment: This link is broken to 404. Can you please make a new source available (you also have posted that link [here](http://www.as3gamegears.com/air-native-extension/ane-imagepicker/) and I could not found you on twitter to ask you, if you could share the source with me. I'm therefore glad I stumbled upon you again here in SO)